# how to make advanceed search using Knockout javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm working on task in MVVM and using Knockout and Durandal for Single page application but i'm new on this issue and i need to make advanced search

the issue is :
I've two comboboxs made with Infragistics 
 first for Countries as Autocomplete and it bind correctly from DB (this is working)

```
<input id="iGCboxFromDest" data-bind="igCombo: {
dataSource: $root.countriesList,
text: countryID,
autoComplete: true,
showDropDownButton: false,
textKey: 'name',
valueKey: 'id',
width: 265,
mode: 'editable',
enableClearButton: false,
filteringType: 'local',
renderMatchItems: 'startsWith'
}" />
```

second for Cities and i need to filter it as per Country

,how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmccowat/GN66G/3/) to show it one idea of how to do it using two select inputs as you mentioned comboboxes.

Basically, you need to bind the selected value of what you are trying to filter on to an observable. In my example, I have an array of Countries and an array of towns (or cities!) which have a relationship to Country by CountryId.

```
countries = ko.observableArray([{"Id":1, "Name": England"}, //etc.]);
towns = ko.observableArray([{"CountryId":1,"Name":"London"},{"CountryId":2,"Name":"Glasgow"},{"CountryId":3,"Name":"Cardiff"},{"CountryId":4,"Name":"Belfast"}]);
```

and the selected country is bound to an observable

```
selectedCountry = ko.observable();
```

and then, I bind these to a select box

```
<select id="countries" data-bind="value: selectedCountry, options: countries, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id',  optionsCaption: 'Countries'"></select>
```

Now we have to filter towns by countryId

```
filteredTowns = ko.computed(function() {
   return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.towns(), function(item) {
        return item.CountryId === self.selectedCountry();
    });  
});
```

and the second select box, bound to the filtered towns should now show the towns related to that city.

```
<select id="towns" data-bind="value: selectedTown, options: filteredTowns, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'CountryId',  optionsCaption: 'towns'"></select>
```

Comment: it's working great as in html tag but how about the igCombo -- Infragistics is there is any detail to add into ?

Comment: I haven't used Infragistics but the following post mentions them supporting it in v 13.1. They also seem to have a cascading dropdown which may make this simpler. http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/jason_beres/archive/2013/03/25/ignite-ui-what-s-new-in-13-1-html5-jquery-amp-mvc-controls.aspx